# Paypal integration without customer filling in billing / shipping

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

Is there a a paypal integration where the customer view's their cart and can click checkout and pay with paypal without filling out the shipping fields.

I want the quickest and slickest possible checkout without the customer filling out any fields what so ever and then requesting it from paypal using the API.

I was looking at the express checkout but it seems to need a shipping fields on our side.

There is so many paypal integration types and documentation that my head is starting to spin.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal's [One Touch](https://www.paypal.com/ie/webapps/mpp/one-touch-checkout/faq) is enabled on buyer's end, but something tells me you'd like the philosophy behind it :)

As far as integration is concerned, limit the fields using variables like no_note and no_shipping.

If you think **cart**, you may like this:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&add=1&currency_code=USD&amount=1&item_name=item&business=youremail@here.com&no_shipping=1&no_note=1

Replace **youremail@here.com** with your email.

Variable reference [[ here ]](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).